# How to get parent node's parent node in XML

Tags: xml, perl, parent

I'm using the XML::Parser to parse different XML files and put their content into the database. Since the structure of the files can vary from file to file, I can't hardcode any node name in my code. At some point I need to know the parent node's parent node. Is it possible to get it somehow?

Here's my current script:

```
use XML::Parser;
use XML::Parser::Nodes;
use DBI qw(:sql_types);
use Error qw(:try);

my %var;

my $filename='x.xml';

my $parser=XML::Parser->new(Style=>'Nodes', Handlers=>{
  Init => \&handle_doc_start
  , Final => \&handle_doc_end
  , Start=>\&handle_start
  , End=>\&handle_end
  , Char=>\&handle_char
  , Default=>\&handle_default });
$parser->parsefile( $filename );

sub handle_doc_start { }
sub handle_doc_end { }

sub handle_start {
  my($expat,$element,%attrs) = @_;

  my $row_id=$expat->element_index;
  my $depth=$expat->depth;
  my $parent=$expat->current_element;

  if (defined($var{$parent.$element.$depth})) { $var{$parent.$element.$depth}++; }
  else { $var{$parent.$element.$depth}=1; }

  # write the tags/elements data into the database

  if(%attrs) {
    while (my ($key,$value)=each(%attrs)) {
      # write the attributes into the database
    }
  }
}

sub handle_end {}

sub handle_char {
  my ($expat,$data) = @_;
  my $row_id=$expat->element_index;

  chomp $data;
  $data=~ s/^\s+//; $data=~ s/\s+$//;

  if (defined($data) && ($data ne '')) {
    # write the values into the database
  }
}

sub handle_default {}
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the `context` method?

```
context
           Returns a list of element names that represent open elements, with
           the last one being the innermost. Inside start and end tag handlers,
           this will be the tag of the parent element.
```

BTW, I am not sure mixing XML::Parser::Nodes and handlers is a good idea. Since XML::Parser::Nodes declares its own handlers (mostly re-using XML::Parser's Tree style handlers) I strongly suspect either your handlers or XML::Parser::Nodes' are ignored. If your handlers are run then it looks like you could get rid of XML::Parser::Nodes.

Comment: The use XML::Parser::Nodes is just a left-over :) I just wanted to try it out, but as you've already mentioned, it wasn't a good idea to mix it with XML::Parser.

Comment: It made helping you more difficult though

Comment: Well, I've managed to get the full parent path, so basically I have the solution for my original question :) Thank you very much.